# In Angular is there a way to wait for a promise before changing the location?

Tags: angularjs

I know that it is possible to wait for a promise to be resolved before loading a new location, but is there a way to wait for a promise *before leaving the current location*?

The use case is unlocking a resource corresponding to the page where the user is. We want to unlock it in any case, and that will need a call to the server. We don't want to leave the page if the corresponding resource is not locked.

Looking in the docs, i see that changing a route can be detected with signals, but there is no way to block a signal waiting for the result of a promise, as far as i know.

The only solution i can think about is:

- Intercept the first route change signal, prevent default to prevent the location change
- Do all asynchronous cleanup operations
- Trigger a route change again, letting it finish this time

Any better/more idiomatic way? I am mainly interested in Angular 1 but also answers about Angular 2 are helpful

Comment: Can you show us your code, what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Currently i am going for something like:

```
'use strict'


angular.module('app')
  .service('beforeLocationChange', function ($rootScope, $location) {
    function makeRelative (location) {
      var start = $location.absUrl().lastIndexOf($location.url())
      return location.substring(start)
    }
    /* Careful! `fun` might be called several times before the
     * listener gets deregistered, thus it has to be idempotent and
     * possibly return a rejection for the calls after the first */
    this.do = function (fun) {
      var deregister = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (
        event,
        newUrl
      ) {
        event.preventDefault()
        fun()
          .catch(function () {
            throw 'The action before location change failed!'
          })
          .finally(function () {
            deregister()
            $location.path(makeRelative(newUrl))
          })
      })

    }
  })
```

This service can be injected in any controller and used within a page controller like this:

```
    beforeLocationChange.do(function () {
        return cleanup() // cleanup code has to return a promise
    })
```

The catch is that `cleanup()` has to be idempotent. This is not a problem in my case and for cleanup code in general

---

#### Edit:

This does not cover the case of the user closing her browser or navigating away from the app without triggering an Angular route event, but i cannot find an effective way to handle that case. Both the Angular `$destroy` event and the DOM `beforeunload` event do not provide a way to stop and wait for asynchronous calls to terminate